# Handle NetworkException in Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I've the following Listener - Producer in Spring Cloud Stream:

```
@StreamListener(target = MultipleProcessor.DOTCONN_INPUT, condition= "headers['kafka_receivedTopic']=='dotconnectorissues'")
public void inputDot(Message<DotConnectorIssue> messageIn) {
    DotConnectorIssue data = messageIn.getPayload();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DotConnectorUpdateDto dataMapped = new DotConnectorUpdateDto(data);
    if (dataMapped.getPlantCode().equals(plantCode)) {
        log.info("incoming dotConnectorIssue " + data);
        try {
            Message<String> messageOut = MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(mapper.writeValueAsString(dataMapped))
                    .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .setHeader("type", "dotconnectorissue")
                    .build();

            boolean send = ehProcessor.outputAndon().send(messageOut, 15000L);
            log.info("sent message: "+ send);
            if (!send) messagePool.getPool().add(messageOut);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("error during creating json", e);
        }
    }

}
```

the piece of code works but, sometimes the message fail to be sent because of the following error:

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener.onError - 
Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 85, 80, 68, 65, 84, 69, 95, 68, 79, 84, 67, 79, 78, 78, 69...' to topic andon:
```

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.`

also if the send variable is true.

How can I handle the NetworkException error in Spring Cloud Stream?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`sync` property to `true`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties) and catch the exception or, to get the error asynchronously, set the producer property `errorChannelEnabled`.

Comment: Thanks for the support! I've tried to set the properies but I think there's something missing because doesn't seems that the message handling is sincronous. I've setted on application.properties: 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.andonOutput.destination=andon

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.andonInput.destination=andon

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.andonOutput.max-attempts=5

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.andonOutput.producer.sync=true

Do you see something strange in the config?

Comment: I see you are new here. Don't put code/config like that in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead and add a comment to say you have done so. The `sync` property is specific to the kafka binder so it needs a `.kafka` element - see the documentation I pointed you to `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.sync=true`.